# How to disable or remove fullscreen button in MPMoviePlayerController [SWIFT]?

Tags: objective-c, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I need to disable or remove the fullscreen button from my video-player. This doesn't work:

```
moviePlayer.fullscreen = false
```

I've searched and found only some old objective-c solutions. Is there some way to make it happen in swift ?

Answer (score 2):

I've never done swift, but I saw a solution for this in Obj-C:

```
[_moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
```

In Swift it may be:

```
moviePlayer?.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
```

Can you tell us if it works?

Comment: Well, actually it works but the player doesn't look nice http://imgur.com/NyBvnvM